# How to change the values of XML as per condition using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like:

```
<all>
    <one>Something 1</one>
    <two>something 2</two>
    <check>
        <present>true</present>
    </check>
    <action>
        <perform></perform>
    </action>
</all>
```

I want to perform XML Transformation using XSL:

expected output:
if `<present>true</present>`

```
all>
    <one>Something 1</one>
    <two>something 2</two>
    <check>
        <present>YES</present>
    </check>
    <action>
        <perform>READ</perform>
    </action>
</all>
```

else if : `<present>false</present>`

```
<all>
    <one>Something 1</one>
    <two>something 2</two>
    <check>
        <present>NO</present>
    </check>
    <action>
        <perform>INSERT</perform>
    </action>
</all>
```

Is it possible to Do?
I am not aware about condition checking in XSL
I try to move the element but did not worked:

```
  <xsl:template match="perform">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="../check/present = 'true'">
        <xsl:text>READ</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do exactly what you say needs to be done:

```
<xsl:template match="perform">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../../check/present='true'">READ</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="../../check/present='false'">INSERT</xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version= "1.0"
xmlns:xsl ="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method= "xml" version= "1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" indent= "yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements= "*" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match= "@*|node()" >
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template >

<xsl:template match="action"/>

<xsl:template match="check/present">
     <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=".='true'">
               <xsl:copy><xsl:text>YES</xsl:text></xsl:copy>
               <action>
                    <perform><xsl:text>READ</xsl:text></perform>
              </action>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:copy><xsl:text>NO</xsl:text></xsl:copy>
               <action>
                    <perform><xsl:text>INSERT</xsl:text></perform>
              </action>
          </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have one more concern. Just wanted to know is it possible to put the xsl file in git repo and read its contends on local and do the transformation